# Why cant I use a space when creating this table?

Tags: sqlite

I am using SQlite3 in Visual Studio code. My goal is to create a table within a database and then import data in that table. The code works fine except for when there is a space involved in the header. The header for the column is "Order ID". When I get rid of the space and import the data it works fine but when I use the space it inputs "order ID" into every spot. Below is the code I am using.

CREATE TABLE Returnedsss
(
Returned  Text ,
'Order ID'  Text ,
PRIMARY KEY ('Order ID')
)
;

.tables

.mode csv
.separator ,
.import --csv "C://Business_Analytics//SQlite//data//Returns.csv" Returnedsss

SELECT 'Order ID'
FROM Returnedsss;

I tried the above and the output is

"Order ID"
"Order ID"
"Order ID"
"Order ID"

When I change it to get rid of the space though and run this code though it runs fine and gives me the Order IDs as an output:

CREATE TABLE Returnedsss
(
Returned  Text ,
OrderID  Text ,
PRIMARY KEY (OrderID)
)
;

.tables

.mode csv
.separator ,
.import --csv "C://Business_Analytics//SQlite//data//Returns.csv" Returnedsss

SELECT OrderID
FROM Returnedsss;

Is there a way to do it where it lets me use the Order ID instead of having to do OrderID?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
SELECT `Order ID` FROM Returnedsss;
```

or

```
SELECT [Order ID] FROM Returnedsss;
```

or

```
SELECT "Order ID" FROM Returnedsss;
```

The issue is how single quotes are used to enclose a literal value character string in preference to enclosing a component name (column table etc).

Answer (score 1):

In SQLite, single quotes `'`...`'` denote a string literal.  If you want to “quote” a column/table/identifier name that contains a space, [there are three ways to do it](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html):

- `"identifier"` (double quotes) — This is the standard SQL syntax.
- `[identifier]` (square brackets) — This is the Microsoft syntax, included in SQLite for compatibility.
- `` `identifier` `` (grave accents) — This is the MySQL syntax, included in SQLite for compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. I was using ' and I needed to use `